# CSS ZOOM causes page content to no longer be centered on browser page

Tags: css, alignment, zooming

I downloaded a pre-made layout for a simple website. However, the original scale is quite small which makes it hard to read the text on the site. That is why I want to use the css zoom argument to enlarge the page :

```
body {margin:0px; padding:0px; background-image:url(images/background.jpg); background-repeat:repeat; zoom:140%}
```

This seems to work but this also causes the content of the page to no longer be centered.

```
(example of the problem: http://217.199.187.69/testaccountarne.be/ )
```

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Thanks,
Arne

P.S. As you probably already noticed, i'm a CSS novice.

Comment: It's better to forget about the `zoom` and to change the `font-size` instead. (That is, everywhere where it says `font-size:10px`, change to `font-size:14px`.) Then your site will look the same in all browsers, even the ones that don't support the `zoom` property!

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you for your answer, but then only the font size will be bigger. I also want the images to become bigger. Else the numer of characters per line will be too low. So i don't want to only change the font size, but also the size of the website as a whole (the header, menu,...). Or is there an easy way to change the style.css file so that all files will also be bigger, without using the zoom property?

Comment: Hm, you mean all the graphics are really too small? Then, how about changing them all with a graphics editor. Or, go look for different images. If the basic material doesn't fit your needs, search for something that does. Otherwise the whole thing will just be sloppy.

Comment: I have the PSD which was used to export all the images & html, but I don't know how to enlarge the whole thing and then export it like that in photoshop...